# can not load style sheet

Tags: html, css, rust, rust-rocket

I am using rocket to make a web server that serves markdown as html.  It was going OK until
I tried to use css.  It loads, but my CSS settings were not working.  When I opened up the Inspector, It gave this error:

```
can not load style sheet
```

[my rust code](https://pastebin.com/nT1kY5Ps)

```
    use markdown::*;
use rocket::response::content;
use rocket::response::content::Html;
use rocket::*;
use serde_derive::Deserialize;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::ops::Add;
use tokio::*;
use toml;
 
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    pubdir: String,
    cssfile: String,
}
 
#[launch]
async fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![getmd, getcssfile])
}
 
#[get("/<path>")]
fn getmd(path: &str) -> Html<String> {
    let mdp = getconf().unwrap().pubdir + path;
    println!("{}", mdp);
    let mut mdf = File::open(&mdp);
    let mut md = String::new();
 
    mdf.unwrap().read_to_string(&mut md);
 
    let html = addcss(gethtm(&md));
    println!("{}", html);
    return content::Html(html);
}
 
#[get("/css.css")]
fn getcssfile() -> String {
    let css = File::open(getconf().unwrap().cssfile);
    let mut csstext = String::new();
    css.unwrap().read_to_string(&mut csstext);
    println!("{}", csstext);
    csstext
}
 
fn getconf() -> Result<Config, toml::de::Error> {
    let mut cFile = File::open("config.toml");
    let mut cString = String::new();
 
    cFile.unwrap().read_to_string(&mut cString);
    println!("a");
    //let config: Result<Config, toml::de::Error> = toml::from_str(&cString);
    return toml::from_str(&cString);
}
 
fn gethtm(md: &str) -> String {
    println!("b");
    return markdown::to_html(md);
}
 
fn addcss(htm: String) -> String {
    println!("{}", htm);
    let mut ohtml = htm.clone();
    let mut h = String::new();
    let hh = h.clone().add(&("
        <head>
            <link rel=\u{0022}stylesheet\u{0022} type=\u{0022}text/css\u{0022} href=\u{0022}css.css\u{0022}>
        </head>
        
        <body>".to_owned()
        + 
        &htm
        + 
        &"</body>".to_owned()));
    //h.add(&htm);
    //h.add("</body>");
    ohtml.insert_str(htm.len(), "</body>");
    println!("{}", ohtml);
    return hh;
}
```

[my css](https://pastebin.com/iGxmNeEm)

```
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

[what my browser shows in the "view source"(for the test text I just mashed my keyboard)](https://pastebin.com/6cLX17ve)

```
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
        </head>
        
        <body><h1 id='oiuuoiuiouoi'>oiuuoiuiouoi</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Show your rust code.

Comment: I added a link to it in pastebin

Comment: We need to more specifically know what error you're getting in the browser. 404? content-type mismatch?

Comment: Is "can not load style sheet" the exact error message you're getting? Can you post a screenshot or the full error message?

Comment: [here is the picture](https://imgur.com/a/PPuDoZQ)

Comment: @moth can you try returning `rocket::response::content::Css(csstext)` from `fn getcssfile()`?

Comment: yes, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you entered the file path to the stylesheet correctly. (This is the only idea i've to this problem). Maybe you can add an inline css sheet in you rust-code.
This could be wrong:

```
<link rel=\u{0022}stylesheet\u{0022} type=\u{0022}text/css\u{0022} href=\u{0022}css.css\u{0022}>
```

Maybe you can use this:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=../styles/base.css">
```

Comment: My server only serves markdown files, so I have a special route for CSS.  see the getcss function

Comment: Hmmm, I see. A more complex solution would be to have an HTML page written (possibly via RUST). There is bound to be an MD -> HTML converter on the web.

Comment: i'm coding this for fun, really just to practice rust

Comment: Ok, nice, Have fun :-)